# Cloud Foundry Java Client Library throws CloudFoundryException: 403 Access token denied

Tags: swisscomdev

An App (Java Buildpack) using the [CF Java Client Library](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/apps/buildpacks/java/java-client.html) to login to CF and connect to another App a `CloudFoundryException: 403 Access token denied` is thrown (see stacktrace below).

The same setup runs on [Pivotal Web Services](http://run.pivotal.io).

The App setup was also fine on the former Nova Swisscom App Cloud. Once the current Swisscom App Cloud was going live the App using the CF Java Client Lib on the Nova App Cloud stopped working with the same Exception.
Maybe that's related with the Swisscom App Cloud integration of the Passport login service which is causing the OAuth token problems.

While still wanting to use the CF Java Lib within a Java-App is there a different way to login to CF and connect to another App?

Stacktrace:

```
2015-10-23T19:26:03.41+0200 [App/0]      OUT org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryException: 403 Access token denied.
2015-10-23T19:26:03.41+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.oauth2.OauthClient.createToken(OauthClient.java:114) ~[cloudfoundry-client-lib-1.1.3.jar!/:na]
2015-10-23T19:26:03.41+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.oauth2.OauthClient.init(OauthClient.java:70) ~[cloudfoundry-client-lib-1.1.3.jar!/:na]
2015-10-23T19:26:03.41+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.initialize(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:187) ~[cloudfoundry-client-lib-1.1.3.jar!/:na]
2015-10-23T19:26:03.41+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.<init>(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:163) ~[cloudfoundry-client-lib-1.1.3.jar!/:na]
2015-10-23T19:26:03.41+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.<init>(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:172) ~[cloudfoundry-client-lib-1.1.3.jar!/:na]
2015-10-23T19:26:03.41+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientFactory.newCloudController(CloudControllerClientFactory.java:78) ~[cloudfoundry-client-lib-1.1.3.jar!/:na]
2015-10-23T19:26:03.41+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryClient.<init>(CloudFoundryClient.java:164) ~[cloudfoundry-client-lib-1.1.3.jar!/:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

swisscom dev here;

We fixed this issue with an update this morning - authentication with your Swisscom Passeport account should now be working from inside the Appcloud.

Comment: Which kind of update did you install to fix this issue?

Comment: @Stefan: It was the issue that access from within the Appcloud hit a different endpoint than from the outside. The fix was to align this.